# Exchange - logging in with email address different from UPN

Tags: active-directory, exchange

How to configure Exchange to enable logging in with Email address, preferably without changing `userPrincipalName` attribute in AD?

AD domain is `example.com` therefore typical `userPrincipalName` is `username@example.com`. However email addresses look different - `givenname.surname@example.net` i.e. in different domain and contain person name instead of username.

What are the options?

*Unfortunately I'm not a system administrator neither experienced with MS products. Detailed answers are appreciated.*

Comment: I also tried setting ```sAMAccountName``` to email address, but it has a limit of 20 characters.

Comment: `What are the options?` - Unfortunately none. An email address isn't a valid "username" unless it's also the UPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why?

For detailed answer... By definition of [User-Principal-Name attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680857(v=vs.85).aspx):

> This attribute contains the UPN that is an Internet-style login name
>   for a user based on the Internet standard [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt). The UPN is shorter
>   than the distinguished name and easier to remember. By convention,
>   this should map to the user email name.

So UPN is the only valid login name for user and by convention (and for better user experience) it should be same as the primary email address set in [Proxy-Addresses attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679424(v=vs.85).aspx). Even when you [add or remove email addresses](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123794(v=exchg.160).aspx) in Exchange admin center EAC or by using the Exchange Management Shell it will actually change your Proxy-Addresses:

> The additional addresses are called proxy addresses. A proxy address
>   lets a user receive email that’s sent to a different email address.
>   Any email message sent to the user's proxy address is delivered to
>   their primary email address, which is also known as the *primary SMTP
>   address* or the *default reply address*.

In multi-domain systems you can achieve this by ensuring that both parts of the UPN

- UPN prefix aka *user account name* and
- UPN suffix aka *DNS domain name*

matches the *primary SMTP address*. The UPN suffix doesn't depend on the *Active Directory domain* (collection of objects) where the OU and the user are stored as it can also be another domain from the forest or any domain listed in [UPN-Suffixes attribute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772007(v=ws.11).aspx).

A UPN suffix has the following restrictions (from [User Naming Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> - It must be the DNS name of a domain, but does not need to be the name of the domain that contains the user.
> - It must be the name of a domain in the current domain forest, or an alternate name listed in the **upnSuffixes** attribute of the Partitions
>     container within the Configuration container.

---

### How?

As described above, **you need to change the `userPrincipalName`**. However, you don't have to change your AD domain name as you can [Add User Principal Name Suffixes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772007(v=ws.11).aspx):

> 1. Open *Active Directory Domains and Trusts*. To open Active Directory
>      Domains and Trusts, click **Start**, click **Administrative Tools**, and
>      then click **Active Directory Domains and Trusts**.
> 2. In the console tree, right-click **Active Directory Domains and Trusts**,
>      and then click **Properties**.
> 3. On the **UPN Suffixes** tab, type an alternative UPN
>      suffix for the forest, and then click **Add**.
> 4. Repeat step 3 to add additional alternative UPN suffixes.

The additional domains will appear on the suffix side of *Account: User logon name* in User Properties window and you can change it to match the *primary SMTP address*.

Your prefix didn't match, either. I suggest changing your usernames to match the `givenname.surname` prefix used in your email addresses. Usernames aren't limited to 20 characters anymore. However, if some local systems are limited to shorter usernames, you can preserve `sAMAccountName` for that.

Comment: First of all, "Wow!". Unfortunately the option with ```changing your usernames``` is impossible due to some decisions in the existing infrastructure made long long time ago. This (and some more googling) provided more than sufficient information about the problem.